# Removing outliers renders a new distribution that has its own outliers

Tags: mathematical-statistics, density-function, outliers, quantiles, winsorizing

I'm trying to remove all the outliers from a data set. However, after removing them, data points that weren't outliers before are now outliers due to the new distribution. What is the correct statistical procedure for this situation?

Comment: How do you decide what is an outlier?

Comment: Winsorization and truncation are just two examples of how to handle outliers. You seem to have conducted truncation. However, the respective quantiles you "cut off" might have been too small, as you suggest. You could just choose larger quantiles you cut off, if you want to hang on to truncation.

Comment: I can understand how removing outliers only to find that the new distribution has (its own) new outliers can look like a bit of a paradox

Comment: Have you considered that what you are regarding as 'outliers' may be useful observations for analyzing the data at hand. For example, if data are exponentially distributed, then 'outliers' by the 'boxplot' criterion are natural values of the distribution. As you eliminate some 'outliers' the reduced dataset may well show 'outliers' of its own, and so on. For severely skewed distributions such as Pareto (after several such iterations) you can wind up ignoring a substantial and legitimate subset of the data. // Usually it's a bad idea to delete 'outliers' unless you _**know**_ they are faulty.

Comment: To echo @BruceET a bit, defining outliers as those observations a certain distance from the mean/median/IQ range is not generally helpful, because there is nothing necessarily "wrong" with that data. For example, if you're trying to estimate the variance and you eliminate those points, you will be underestimating the variance. Outliers should be defined as those observations that you believe were *generated by a different distribution* than the rest of your data, and hence don't help you estimate something about the distribution of interest.

Comment: To use Hawkins' definition [Hawkins 1980]: “An outlier is an observation which deviates so much from the other observations as to arouse suspicions that it was generated by a different mechanism." You should have either strong evidence or strong prior belief that some of your data is generated by a different mechanism/distribution before you throw those data points away.

Comment: Just keep deleting them until there is no more data.  Problem solved.

Comment: I keep deleting them until i get less than 0.5% outliers

Answer (score 1):

Lognormal data is often encountered in practice. Here is a session in R
that begins with $n_1 = 1000$ observations from a lognormal distribution.
At the start, the sample mean is $\bar Y_1 = 1.70$ and the sample standard
deviation is $S_1 = 2.49.$ Then we go through several iterations, removing
boxplot outliers at each step. [Computations in R.]

```
set.seed(2020)
y1= rlnorm(1000)
summary(y1); length(y1); sd(y1)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
 0.04217  0.49016  0.94409  1.69558  1.89374 40.56466 
[1] 1000
[1] 2.493404

y2 = y1[y1 <= boxplot.stats(y1)$stats[5]]
summary(y2); length(y2); sd(y2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.04217 0.46651 0.85522 1.11458 1.53644 3.97491 
[1] 911
[1] 0.8619062

y3 = y2[y2 <= boxplot.stats(y2)$stats[5]]
summary(y3); length(y3); sd(y3)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.04217 0.44789 0.82218 1.01352 1.41563 3.13268 
[1] 874
[1] 0.7214308

y4 = y3[y3 <= boxplot.stats(y3)$stats[5]]
summary(y4); length(y4); sd(y4)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.04217 0.44615 0.80870 0.98817 1.38893 2.86639 
[1] 863
[1] 0.6898908

y5 = y4[y4 <= boxplot.stats(y4)$stats[5]]
summary(y5); length(y5); sd(y5)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.04217 0.44576 0.80567 0.97515 1.38133 2.79356 
[1] 857
[1] 0.6744334
```

With successive 'outlier' removals, the sample size has fallen
to 911, 874, 863, and finally, $n_5 =$ 857. So I'm down to less than 86% of my
original data, with no end of removals yet in sight. The sample
mean has decreased from 1.70 for the full sample to 0.975, and the standard deviation
from 2.49 to 0.674.

> One has to wonder what population the final sample in this sequence might represent. Certainly, not the same population that the original sample came from.

Here are boxplots for the original sample (at left) and the multiply-truncated sample `y5` (right).

```
boxplot(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

To be clear, there is nothing unusual about the original sample above. Here are boxplots for 20 samples of size 1000 from the same population. Every one of the 20 samples has multiple boxplot outliers.

```
set.seed(1021)
m = 20;  n = 1000
x = rlnorm(m*n);  gp = rep(1:20, each=n)
boxplot(x ~ gp, col="skyblue2", main="Boxplots of 20 Lognormal Samples")
```

[image]

A simulation with 100,000 samples of size 1000 shows that the average number of
(first pass) boxplot outliers per sample is about 76.

```
set.seed(1234)
nr.out = replicate(10^5, length(boxplot.stats(rlnorm(1000))$out))
mean(nr.out)
[1] 77.53626
```

If an outcome is known to have resulted from equipment failure or data entry error,
then, of course, it should be excluded. Also, there may be times when you know
a value is simply impossible (e.g., a negative height or a human lifetime over 900 years)
and needs to be ignored. But I think it is a serious mistake to establish an
automated process for 'outlier' removal--particularly an iterative one. Sometimes real data show surprisingly good or disastrously bad news. It's a good idea to pay attention when that happens.

Comment: (+1): What made you choose lognormal distribution? Is there a clear flaw in outlier identification in boxplots that helped in making the choice of distribution?

Comment: when do i stop? when outlier is less than xx % of the data?